# permission denied for function table_import_from_s3

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-rds

Trying to get a file from s3 to Postgres and I'm seeing this error:

```
ERROR:  permission denied for function table_import_from_s3
```

This is what I'm trying:

```
SELECT aws_s3.table_import_from_s3(
'btr.Ats_20210304',
'ID,NAME,WEBSITE,TYPE,CATEGORY,SUB_CATEGORY,PARENT_ACCOUNT,PARENT_ACCOUNT_ID,REGION,SEGMENT,HOLDING_COMPANY,CUSTOM_FIELDS,TEAM,EMAIL,STREET1,STREET2,CITY,STATE,ZIP,PHONE,COUNTRY,MOBILE,CREATED_BY,UPDATED_BY,UPDATE_AT',
'(FORMAT csv, HEADER true, DELIMITER ",")',
'vdw-dev',
'date/hourly/data_0_0_0.csv.gz',
'us-east-1');
```

Comment: I'm guessing either/or combination of 1) Postgres user running function does have permissions on it 2) The RDS instance does not have permissions on the S3 bucket. For that see here [S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/PostgreSQL.Procedural.Importing.html) Setting up access to an Amazon S3 bucket .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed by granting permissions in Postgres:

```
GRANT ALL ON ALL FUNCTIONS IN SCHEMA aws_s3 TO 'user';
```

Comment: Or, to grant it to everyone, use `TO public`

Answer (score 14):

The following statements grant enough privileges to a user to run the extension functions:

```
GRANT USAGE ON schema aws_s3 TO myuser;

GRANT EXECUTE ON ALL FUNCTIONS IN SCHEMA aws_s3 TO myuser;
```

Comment: this is the better answer, the accepted did not work for me